# How to pass hook function to react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have been unsuccessful at passing a State Hook to a child functional component in React Js. The passed function prints undefined and the console says "error signing in TypeError: updateUser is not a function". The parent component is the App.js component and the child component is LoginPage.js. My end goal is ensure the user is authenticated throughout the app using AWS Cognito/AWS Amplify. If the user state is not authenticated, I send the user to the LoginPage.

Specifically, as seen below, i pass "updateUser={updateUser}" to the LoginPage.js component, it is read as "LoginPage({updateUser})", and used as "updateUser(user)". The simplified parent and child components are as followed:

```
function App() {

    const [user, updateUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        checkUser()
    }, []
    )

    async function checkUser() {
        try {
            const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
            updateUser(user)
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    if (!user) {
        return <LoginPage updateUser={updateUser} />
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" component={LoginPage} exact />
                        <Route path="/HomePage" component={HomePage} exact />
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;

        export default function LoginPage({updateUser}) {
    
    async function signIn(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const {email, password} = formState
        try {
            await Auth.signIn(email, password);
 
            const user  = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();

            console.log(updateUser) // updateUser is undefined

            updateUser(user)
            })

        } catch (error) {
           console.log(error)
        }
    }

    return (
                <div>
                    // Login page here, but irrelevant
                <div>
)
}

LoginPage.propTypes = {
    updateUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in both cases, that is when user is authenticated as well as when user is not authenticated, you are rendering the `LoginPage`.

So you have to either update your logic to show `LoginPage` component only when the user is not logged in or if you want to keep same logic, then in the `else` condition in `App` component, you have to pass in a render prop function called `updateUser`, such that it doesn't lead to error, like so:

```js
<Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <LoginPage updateUser={(args) => console.log("Your update function")} {...props} />} />
```

I recommend modifying your logic and going with my former suggestion.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for the suggestion! I implemented the suggested line and it solved the underfined function issue! I will now rework the logic. Gratitude for your advice!